# Concatenate time into sql string

Tags: sql, ssms, string-concatenation

I am trying to execute a stored procedure with parameters of int, varchar,varchar,varchar.

Inside of the last one, the element Step has an attribute start, where i want to hold the value of the current datetime. How can I concatenante this into a string.

The Error:

```
  Incorrect Syntax Near '+'


EXEC spData_Update @num,'<Info></Info>','<Metrics></Metrics>',
'<step start="' + SELECT CONVERT(varchar(50),getdate()) + '" end="" user="InsertFromWeb">
  <type id="1" value="2" />
  <type id="2" value="0" />
  <type id="3" value="0" />
  <type id="4" value="0" />
 </step>'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can declare a variable to hold the last string.

```
declare @date varchar(1000)

set @date = (select
'<step start="' + CONVERT(varchar(50),getdate()) + '" end="" user="InsertFromWeb">
  <type id="1" value="2" />
  <type id="2" value="0" />
  <type id="3" value="0" />
  <type id="4" value="0" />
 </step>')

EXEC spData_Update @num,'<Info></Info>','<Metrics></Metrics>', @date
```